# Using jQuery to Remove and Add Data Attribute for fancybox2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox-2

I am trying to add a filterable "gallery" to a WordPress site using fancybox. Elements are grouped using both rel and data-fancybox-group. The data attribute takes precedence over the rel group. Is there a way to delete the data-fancybox-group data attribute when any other filter but the "all" filter is clicked. If the all filter is clicked, the data-fancybox-group="all" should be added if it does not exist.

```
<ul id="portfolio-filter">
    <li> <a href="#all" class="filter all active" data-filter"all"> All </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#filter-1" class="filter" data-filter".filter-1"> Filter 1 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#filter-2" class="filter" data-filter".filter-2"> Filter 2 </a> </li>
</ul>

<div id="portfolio-wrapper" class="row">
    <div id="portfolio" class="p_container">
        <ul id="portfolio-list">
            <li class="portfolio-item mix filter-1">
                <a class="fancybox thumbnail" data-fancybox-group="all" rel="filter1">
                    <img src="..." />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-item mix filter-1">
                <a class="fancybox thumbnail" data-fancybox-group="all" rel="filter1">
                    <img src="..." />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-item mix filter-2">
                <a class="fancybox thumbnail" data-fancybox-group="all" rel="filter2">
                    <img src="..." />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-item mix filter-2">
                <a class="fancybox thumbnail" data-fancybox-group="all" rel="filter2">
                    <img src="..." />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I have come up with a solution. Feel free to recommend a better way.

```
<script>
        jQuery(function(){
                jQuery(".filter").click(function()
                {
                        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('all') ){
                            alert('This is NOT THEALL filter!');
                            jQuery( ".fancybox.thumbnail" ).each(function() {
                                if(jQuery(this).attr('data-fancybox-group')) {

                                    jQuery(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "");
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else{
                                //alert('This is the ALL assigned Filter!');
                                if (!jQuery( ".fancybox.thumbnail").hasClass('all') ){
                                        jQuery( ".fancybox.thumbnail" ).each(function() {
                                        jQuery(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "all");        
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You may not need to use `rel` neither removing the `data` attribute. You could actually change its value on the fly to filter your gallery. I wrote a post (with demo) a year ago or so you may want to read http://www.picssel.com/create-a-filtered-image-gallery-with-jquery-and-fancybox/

Answer (score 0):

You can access dataset members of a DOM element through the native [HTMLelement.dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). You can use the `delete` keyword to delete a particular element. e.g.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.click').click(function(){
    delete document.getElementById('my-div').dataset.sample;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='my-div' data-sample='Hello, world!'>My div</div>
<a class='click'>Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        jQuery(function(){
                jQuery(".filter").click(function()
                {
                        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('all') ){
                            alert('This is NOT THEALL filter!');
                            jQuery( ".fancybox.thumbnail" ).each(function() {
                                if(jQuery(this).attr('data-fancybox-group')) {

                                    jQuery(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "");
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else{
                                //alert('This is the ALL assigned Filter!');
                                if (!jQuery( ".fancybox.thumbnail").hasClass('all') ){
                                        jQuery( ".fancybox.thumbnail" ).each(function() {
                                        jQuery(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "all");        
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                });
        });
    </script>
```